# How to use directory autocompletion with scp

Tags: ssh, scp

I use the authorized-key to log into my remote ubuntu server. I need to use `scp` frequently to cp files from my local machine to my remote machine. I want to enable the autocompletion as I did with my local machine by `bash-autocompletion`.

How could I do that?

## Updated

I tried `zsh`(https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), the `scp` works fine with auto-completion. How could I do it with my `bash`?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What's the remote server running? ...

Comment: Remote Server is running ubuntu 11.10 and `sshd`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu and Debian to my knowledge bring with the `bash-completion` package exactly the functionality that you ask. However if the remote server has a scheme implemented to thwart break-in attempts (e.g. by limiting the number of connections within a given time interval and blocking if a client exceeds it) you will run into problems.

Check `/etc/bash_completion` on your system and `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh`. If it doesn't exist, make sure to `apt-get install bash-completion`. Once that's done, make sure that your `.bashrc` or `.profile` loads that global auto-completion file.

This brings usually functionality to both auto-complete the remote hostname from your `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` (`grep _known_hosts_real /etc/bash_completion`) and auto-completion for remote folders on `scp`.

One note of caution: if the remote host outputs extra stuff upon login, the auto-completion tends to break. One way to work around this can be (but I found this not to work everywhere) to bail out without any output on the remote machine:

```
[ -z "$SSH_TTY" ] && exit
```

... i.e. show no banner or so. You include this line in `/etc/sshd/sshrc` on the remote box or at the top (below hashbang) of whatever script you are executing to show the ASCII art form of the fingerprint. Note that the above line is bourne-shell syntax, adjust it of needed. It checks whether the `SSH_TTY` env. variable is empty and if so exits with exit code 0.

Comment: But it doesn't even work once... How should I config the `sshd` on the server side to enable this?

Comment: Sheesh - talk about log pollution on the remote server.

Comment: @yangchenyun: nothing to configure on the remote machine other than using `ssh-copy-id` (or manually copying your public key).

Comment: @ErikA: sorry, no idea what you are talking about, but this does in no way require installation of anything on the remote server, other than `sshd` and `sed`, I think ... no "packages" required there at least.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED By "log pollution", I'm referring to the fact that, if this does what I think it does, bash-completion is going to authenticate to the remote server every time you hit tab so it can get the directory listing. The SNR of the logs will just go down significantly. Not a huge deal, but just an observation.

Comment: The bash_completion works fine here. I use `brew install bash-completion` on mac, and I load it with my `.bash_profile` properly. The **one note of caution** might be the causes of problem. I ask the ssh to print to RSA-key img to verify the server identification. Where to use the line `[ -z "$SSH_TTY" ] && exit`?

Comment: @ErikA: gotcha. Fair point, can't argue with that :)

Comment: @yangchenyun: edited my answer to include (hopefully) all info required to include that line or the functionality it provides.

Comment: +1 for outputting "extra stuff upon login"

Answer (score 0):

I guess not, since you don't have access to the remote filesystem until you actually hit enter and authenticate when you are doing SCP.

bash-autocompletion kicks in only after getting successfully logged in to remote server or after loading bash profile which sources bash-completion script in the case of local login.

you might want to look into sshfs which mounts remote filesystem locally and then you can do auto-completion on that.

Comment: nope, that's not correct ;) ... on Debian/Ubuntu please install the package `bash-completion` and check out the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` for an example implementation.

Comment: If you use key authorization, it could work. As the `ssh-agent` will take care of the verification. Also `zsh` could archive this effect but I want to have it on my bash.

Comment: I am aware of that ...please read my answer carefully(2nd paragraph).The guy is asking for autocompletion on remote machine folder while doing SCP from his computer ! Autocomplete works on his computer folders / files but will not work on remote computer's filesystem

Comment: @kaji: and the comment I made was to point out that his local auto-completion can be harnessed to complete file and folder names on `scp` to and from the remote machine (and yes, with the remote file/folder names).

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED thanks i was just defending my answer ;) I will try to see if i could make it work with bash here as you explained